# PowerShell New-ItemProperty to run only if property doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge, internet-options

I'm trying to enable the **Allow active content to run in file on My Computer** with a powershell script. What I found is that PCs where this was never enabled, the registry for this setting was never created. What I want the script to do is check if it exists in the registry, if its not there... then to create it. If it does exist, then to just enable it.

Here is my attempt...

Creation

```
New-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN" -Name iexplore.exe -Value "0" -PropertyType DWord
```

Enabling

```
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN" -Name iexplore.exe -Value "0" -PropertyType DWord
```

Using the above code... i tried using IF Else statement but just can't seem to get it right...

```
If(get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet 
Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN" -Name iexplore.exe){
New-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN" -Name iexplore.exe -Value "0" -PropertyType DWord -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'added Registry value' -f red
}
Else{ 
set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN" -Name iexplore.exe -Value "0"
Write-Host "Active Content is set"
```

Instead I get this error as well as the creation of the registry but not the correct type... which I need in DWord.

```
get-ItemProperty : Property iexplore.exe does not exist at path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN.
At line:2 char:4
+ If(get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (iexplore.exe:String) [Get-ItemProperty], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
 
Active Content is set
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It look like you are doing it backward ? You do `If(get-ItemProperty... THEN New-Item ELSE SET` but this should be the other way around. Here's something that should work.

```
$RegItem = @{
    Path = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN'
    Name = 'iexplore.exe'
}

# Create path if missing
$Path = Get-Item -Path $RegItem.Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($null -eq $Path) { New-Item -Path $RegItem.Path }


if ($null -eq (Get-ItemProperty @RegItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    New-ItemProperty @RegItem -Value "0" -PropertyType DWord -Force | Out-Null
    Write-Host 'added Registry value' -f red
} else {
    set-ItemProperty @RegItem -Value "0"
    Write-Host "Active Content is set"
}
```

**Additional note**

I added a section to create the `FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN` if it is missing and also cleaned your code by removing all the repeat instance of the path / name.